# linkedin OAuth2 returns invalid_redirect_uri error even though the link is registered, working in wix velo

Tags: javascript, node.js, velo

I created in the wix backend a .jsw module to use the linkedin OAuth, my goal is to retrieve the access token after successfully getting the code.

in the front - the on click function:

```
export function linkedinRegister_click(event) {
    const redirectUri = "https://username.wixsite.com";
        const clientId = "someClientId";
        wixLocation.to(`https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&state=STATE&scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress`);
}
```

then to retrieve the code in the front and forward it to the backend function:

```
import {getLinkedinToken} from 'backend/registerModule';

$w.onReady(function () {
    let code;
    if (wixLocation.query.code) {
        code = wixLocation.query.code;
        getLinkedinToken(code);
    }
}
```

in the back - the function to retrieve the token:

```
import { fetch } from 'wix-fetch';

export function getLinkedinToken(code) {
    const clientId = 'someClientId';
    const clientSecret = 'someClientSecret';
    const callbackUrl = "https://username.wixsite.com";

    const link = `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?code=${code}&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&redirect_uri=${callbackUrl}`;

    const fetchOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
    };

    fetch(link, fetchOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log('LinkedIn Access Token:', data))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}
```

Both redirect uris are the same in both functions, the redirect uri is registered in the linkedin developer page

The error i get:

```
"sourceLocation":{
"file":"backend/registerModule.jsw"
"line":59
"column":30
}

"jsonPayload":{
"message":"["LinkedIn Access Token:",{"error":"invalid_redirect_uri","error_description":"Unable to retrieve access token: appid/redirect uri/code verifier does not match authorization code. Or authorization code expired. Or external member binding exists"}]"
}
```

i am clueless what is causing the error

i tried to send the data in the body but that brought up a different error, the error stated that the request was missing a parameter 'grant_type' (invalid_request "A required parameter "grant_type" is missing") even though it was always included.. tried to remove the grant_type parameter and still had the same error.